# Pysimplegui text in the middle of the window

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a single text line in the middle of the window, as in vertically and horizontally, I have been able to get it centered horizontal, but not vertically

This is what I got so far:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

# ----------------  Create Form  ----------------
sg.theme('Black')
sg.set_options(element_padding=(0, 0))

layout = [[sg.Text('')],
         [sg.Text(size=(40, 10), font=('Helvetica Bold', 40), justification='center', key='text', expand_x=True, expand_y=True)]]

window = sg.Window('Running Timer', layout, no_titlebar=False, element_justification='c', auto_size_buttons=False, keep_on_top=True, grab_anywhere=True).Finalize()
window.Maximize()

# ----------------  main loop  ----------------
current_time = 0
paused = False
start_time = int(round(time.time() * 100))
while (True):
    # --------- Read and update window --------
    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)
    current_time = int(round(time.time() * 100)) - start_time
    # --------- Display timer in window --------
    window['text'].update(' {:02d}:{:02d}.{:02d}'.format((current_time // 100) // 60,
                                                                  (current_time // 100) % 60,
                                                                  current_time % 100))
```

Comment: `VPush` element will do what you need.  There is information in the cookbook and eCookbook that shows how they're used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the helper functions `sg.Push()` ad `sg.VPush()`

> Push()
>
> Placing one on each side of an element will center the element horizontally. Place one to the left and the element to the right will be right justified.

> VPush()
>
> Placing one on each side of an element will center the element vertically. Place one to the top and the element to the bottom will be bottom justified.

```py
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Black')
sg.set_options(font=('Helvetica Bold', 40))

layout = [
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text(key='text'),sg.Push()],
    [sg.VPush()],
]
window = sg.Window('Running Timer', layout, finalize=True)
window.maximize()

current_time = 0
start_time = int(round(time.time() * 100))

while (True):

    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        current_time = int(round(time.time() * 100)) - start_time
        window['text'].update(
            '{:02d}:{:02d}.{:02d}'.format(
                (current_time // 100) // 60,
                (current_time // 100) %  60,
                 current_time %  100))

window.close()
```